# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 - Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework, pdo

I get error reports similar to below when security metrics scan our server.

We use `Magento communirt 1.7`.

Help needed thank you.

I can't paste the whole report as it doesn't allow me.

URL: `http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.html?dir=asc&order=bestsellers&p=12&price=50-&limit=100&cat=375%3Cfoo%3Ebar%3C/%20foo%3E`

```
IP Address: 162.211.152.16
Time: 2013-11-19 07:39:42 GMT
```

**Error:**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/ foo>,
>   category_ids)) OR (show_in_subcategories=1 AND
>   (find_in_set(375bar<' at line 1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue was caused by an extension installed. All sorted now